# Pass parameter from controller to services in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How can i have one service or factory receiving two parameters from many controllers?

One parameter for the url, other for the file name to be stored on the filesystem.

I will have many controllers using this service, each passing his own url and filenames that  reads the url and generate a pdf.

I will always store the last downloaded pdf providing an "open last pdf" button, that will use the name parameter.

I will have a "generate new pdf" button coming from the url.

I do follow this tutorial https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/manage-files-in-android-and-ios-using-ionicframework/ and everything works fine.

I am using cordova file-transfer and inappbrowser cordova plugins

---

These sections will receive the parameters :

dirEntry.getFile("pdf-number-1.pdf",

ft.download(encodeURI("http://www.someservice.com"),p,

---

My attempt always trigger the message unknow pdfService provider

Wich concepts of angular i am missing ? How can i fix it ?

In services.js i have :

---

```
.service('pdfService', function($scope, $ionicLoading){

if( window.cordova && window.cordova.InAppBrowser ){
    window.open = window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
    console.log("InAppBrowser available");
  } else {
    console.log("InAppBrowser not available");
  }

  this.download = function() {
    $ionicLoading.show({
      template: 'Loading...'
    });
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs) {
      fs.root.getDirectory("ExampleProject",{create: true},
          function(dirEntry) {
                dirEntry.getFile(
                    "pdf-number-1.pdf", 
                    {
                        create: true, 
                        exclusive: false
                    }, 
                    function gotFileEntry(fe) {
                        var p = fe.toURL();
                        fe.remove();
                        ft = new FileTransfer();
                        ft.download(
                            encodeURI("http://www.someservice.com"),
                            p,
                            function(entry) {
                                $ionicLoading.hide();
                                $scope.imgFile = entry.toURL();
                            },
                            function(error) {
                                $ionicLoading.hide();
                                alert("Download Error Source -> " + error.source);
                            },
                            false,
                            null
                        );                        
                    }, 
                    function() {
                        $ionicLoading.hide();
                        console.log("Get file failed");
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    },
    function() {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        console.log("Request for filesystem failed");
    });
  }

    this.load = function() {
      $ionicLoading.show({
        template: 'Loading...'
      });

      window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs) {
          fs.root.getDirectory(
              "ExampleProject",
              {
                  create: false
              },
              function(dirEntry) {
                  dirEntry.getFile(
                      "pdf-number-1.pdf", 
                      {
                          create: false, 
                          exclusive: false
                      }, 
                      function gotFileEntry(fe) {
                          $ionicLoading.hide();
                          $scope.imgFile = fe.toURL();
                          alert(fe.toURL());
                          window.open(fe.toURL(), '_system', 'location=no,toolbar=yes,closebuttoncaption=Close PDF,enableViewportScale=yes');
                      }, 
                      function(error) {
                          $ionicLoading.hide();
                          console.log("Error getting file");
                      }
                  );
              }
          );
      },
      function() {
          $ionicLoading.hide();
          console.log("Error requesting filesystem");
      });
    }
});
```

---

And in the controller :

```
.controller('SomeCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, pdfService) {

 ...

pdfService.download = function(url) {
  console.log('pdfService download');
}
pdfService.load = function() {
  console.log('pdfService load');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to inject the service to your controllers and call a function with the two params you want as your arguments. 
eg.

```
.service('pdfService', function(){
   var lastUrl;
   var lastFileName
   return {
      createPdf(url, fileName){
          //do processing
          lastUrl = url;
          lastFileName = fileName
      },
      loadLastPdf(){
         //use lastUrl and lastFileName
      }
   }
}
```

and in your controller:

```
.controller('SomeCtrl', function(pdfService) {
    pdfService.createPdf('http://example.com', 'file.pdf');
    // or pdfService.loadLastPdf();
}
```

That being said, the error you are reporting means that the DI is unable to find a service with the name pdfService to inject to your controller. This might be because you forgot to include the service.js file to your html as a script tag (if you are doing it like that) or you forgot to add it as a dependency using require (if you are using sth like browserify) or maybe if you are minifying your code since you are not using the minsafe syntax

Comment: Thank´s mxa055! much clear now, i try to implement but see some simple sintax error : Unexpected token . at line : this.downloadPdf = function(url,fileName) {    the code is here : http://plnkr.co/edit/ASB7LSCuCRvVLGI3Kqxf in case you want to give a help to point the syntax error. Best reards.

Comment: Yes i do include the services js as  `code`<script src="js/services.js"></script>`code` . I am not sure about the way to register the service im my controller i do have : `code`.controller('SomeCtrl',  ['$scope', 'pdfService',function($scope, $ionicPopup, pdfService ) {
...
}])`code`

Comment: You cannot inject $scope into your service, since there is no view to glue it  to. Also in your controller declaration you are missing the minsafe declaration of the $ionicPopup on your comment above. Check this out, maybe is helps http://plnkr.co/edit/S52j3LXvljWS2GJU7P1v?p=preview

Comment: As a improvement how can i use promisses (then) to call the load method if the downloadPdf have sucess? i do try it here on the service after the downloadPdf function [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/ASB7LSCuCRvVLGI3Kqxf?p=preview)

Comment: @ÂngeloRigo I do not thing [Cordoba.FileTransfer](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/) supports promises so either you should wrap it using [$q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) to implement a deferred promise pattern or use a promisification library like [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird). And then you will be able to use it like pdfService.createPdf('url','filename').then(successFunction)